# Add .so files to gradle project for a jar

Tags: android, jar

In my current gradle based project, I'm using a library which depends on already built .so libraries in the armeabi folder in libs.

How can I add those .so files to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a new JAR with the .so files in a lib folder in it. Simpliest way to fix that..

Comment: What I said ? Same thing

Comment: You told me something of NDK build.. But thanks though, never mind